# Getting Scudo error while using a native library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, native

Not able to understand how to debug the Scudo error. Has anyone else fixed a similar issue before?

```
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: corrupted chunk header at address 0x2000072d703d510
```

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue?